# Have a ForeignKey with multiple values? Proper solution?

Tags: python, django

I've decided to embark on the task of creating my own LMS in Django for a final project in my Advanced Python course, unfortunately, I have reached a wall in terms of progress.

I have two models.

- Course model, consists of multiple members (ManyToMany field)
- Profile model, consists of several courses (ForeignKey field)

My question is, how can I have the Profile model linked to multiple courses?

Here is my code so far:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name=("Members"))
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Profile(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=roles)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user', 'password', 'role']
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key relations allow multiple instances of *this* model to be associated with a single instance of the *other* model, i.e.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    courses = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

only allows one `Course` to be associated with a given `Profile` (but multiple `Profile`s can be associated with a single `Course`). You may think of it like a parent > child relation where `Course` is a parent and `Profile`s are children.

If you need to associate multiple `Course`s to be associated with a `Profile` (and still be able to have multiple `Profile`s associated with a `Course`), you should use a `ManyToMany` relation, such as:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    courses = models.ManyToMany(Course)
```

This effectively creates a third, hidden table (called a `through` table) which links both sides:

This is an example of how that through table looks like. Note that you don't have to create this manually as normally there is no model (it is implicit) and the database table is automatically generated by Django:

```
class ProfileCourse(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
```